# How to access functions between different JS files?

Tags: javascript, html, scope

I am trying to separate the logic of my application by using multiple javascript files that focus on certain specific tasks.

The functions defined within the JSfiles need to be accessed between the files themselves.

I understand that the order of calling the functions is important and defining "global" vs "local" scope is important.  In the following files the files are not wrapped in functions so I suppose they are in the global scope.

**file1.js**

```
function addingToDOM(stuff) {
...  
...
}
```

**file2.js**

```
// call addingToDOM
addingToDOM(someStuff);
function doOtherTHings() {
...
...
}
```

**HTML** (order of files)

```
<script src="file1.js"></script>
<script src="file2.js"></script>
```

**ERROR**
`addingToDOM is not defined`

`file2.js` calls `file1.js` after `file1.js` in the HTML.
I don't understand why it's not defined.

Comment: There must be more to it. If `addingToDOM` is defined in global scope, it will work. Since it does not seem to work, you have to provide more information. Is `file1.js` really loaded?

Comment: double checked... wasn't being loaded.  noob mistake.  closing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JS files should just define functions and call ones that are in the same JS file. If you're going to call functions in a JS file from another, that JS file needs to be loaded first. I would put all the calling code (kind of like your "main" function in other languages like C) in one place, preferably at the end of your html document. After all, the other JS files (and the markup) is loaded. It's not that you can't call a function in file1 from file2, it's that they should both be fully loaded before your code begins to run.

Your setup should work as it is, but be sure to call the first function that needs to be run not from within a JS file, but at the end of your HTML document.

Comment: Nice one, Mr. @Tyler. My edit (with the small improvements that I made) was not considered, but you took the chance to edit by yourself. You're doing great :). Congrats.

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks like the quoting of your src attributes in the script tags. Try this in the HTML:

```
<script src="file1.js"></script>
<script src="file2.js"></script>
```

Comment: copy/paste error.  Its double quoted in the source.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like `require.js`: It let's you easily manage dependencies among several JS files, by specifying the order in which modules should be loaded etc.

http://requirejs.org/

Besides that, it is recommended to have only a single JavaScript file with all *your* code (3rd party libraries are usually still separate) in production environments - this file can then be minified, thus making it smaller and faster to download than multiple files. But that's not really important during development, you should just be aware of it.

*Edit:* Btw., `require.js` also provides an easy way to produce a single minified file out of all your modules for production.

Comment: Thanks for the headsUp on the single javascript file